# Plotting the association between two ordinal variables at three points in time

Tags: stata, ordinals

On 6 occasions, the same people were asked to give their opinion on the degree of confidence in their ability to do an action (`pass_t1`, `pass_t3`, `pass_t5`) and whether they did an action (`h_t2`, `h_t4`, `h_t6`).

I want to plot the association between their degree of confidence and their reaction (acted or not) over time. using spearman correlational model

```
spearman pass_t1 h_t2
```

Problem:
degrees of confidence (`pass_t1`, `pass_t3`, `pass_t5`) were measured on an ordinal scale (`0.4` = 'i am somewhat confident' and `1` = 'i am 100% sure') while actions were measured `yes/no = (1/0)`.

[image: representative example data]

Comment: I stopped at calculate the association -- as you don't say how that is done. Also, I can't follow the time structure here.

Comment: i want to use spearman correlation as the variables were measured on an ordinal scale

Comment: Three Spearman correlations? Do you need a graph for that?

Comment: You could just type the correlations in as data points and fire up `graph dot`.